# 'LIKE' keyword is not working in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-like

I have bulk-data in SQL-Server table. One of the fields contains following data :

```
'(اے انسان!) کیا تو نہیں جانتا)'
```

Tried:

```
SELECT * from Ayyat where Data like '%انسان%' ;
```

but it is showing no-result.

Comment: The unicode characters must be followed with `N` so'd be ...like N'%انسان%'

Comment: And remember try to avoid use for field name built-in keyword like `data` and others...

Comment: I didn't know about what vikram told about `N` character. I always convert database and table format...

Comment: but as i mentioned earlier, i just put N before % sign it worked...

Comment: Yeah now I always do as you did. Put `N` character.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Plese use N before string if language is not a english:

```
  SELECT * from Ayyat where Data like N'%انسان%' ;
```

Comment: Hi try it for above solution

Comment: u know, SO takes some time before u accept answer ! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you're storing urdu, arabic or other language except english in your database first you should convert your database into another format and then also table.

first you've to convert your database charset and also collation alter your database

```
ALTER DATABASE database_name CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

then convert your table

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

after this execute normal your query

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE Datas LIKE '%انسان%'
```

**Note:** if you not convert your database and table other languages and special characters will be changed into **question marks**.

Comment: i am working with :
 [Data]  NVARCHAR (MAX) COLLATE Arabic_CI_AI_KS_WS NOT NULL,
and its working fine!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46742/discussion-between-user2727841-and-user3131402)